# Disqus API for getting the list of posts from the forum

Tags: java, api, disqus

I am using the Disqus API for getting the list of posts for a particular forum.
The url that i am using to get the posts is -
'http://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json' 
In the disqus api docs they have provided the parameters that can be passed to the above url. Out of which 'since' is one, which can be used to get all the posts after the specified date.
In the api docs they have mentioned that we can use Unix timestamp (or ISO datetime standard) as the value for the 'since' param. 
I have tried with both types of values but it gives me all the posts i.e. the since constraint is never applied.

Can you please help me out to know how to use 'since' param.

Thanks !!

Comment: the format that they have provided in the api docs works well only thing that confused me and resulted in asking the above question was it also has a 'order' parameter which is by default set to 'desc'.

Comment: have you found out how to use the 'since' param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes the order param is bydefault set to 'desc'...you can get more info on this link:  http://disqus.com/api/docs/forums/listPosts/

Comment: wow, had to dig deep into google search to get that important clue as to how to get the "since" parameter to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I use mootools, can you show me javascript code for that ajax request?

My js is:

```
new Request.JSONP({    
          url :"https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/list.jsonp?api_key=9ldXlWCWlsyjMI3qvf03Y8OQCNxvAMklHkrNVcpBKm220XJHXsU0QDdr0TCLM1kz",//&forum=colourasexperience&thread=ident:cae52020",
          callbackKey: 'showMyInfoes', 
          onSuccess: function(jdata){
                //console.log(jdata);       
          } 
}).send();
```

Thanks